# Android - Library to cache/recall network calls when no Internet

Tags: android, http, caching, networking

I have an application that uses HttpPost, DefaultHttpClient and a ResponseHandler for all my network calls. A problem with the application is that when the user doesn't have Internet, the application pretty much has to block them from doing anything.

I've heard there may be a library that could cache my network calls, and then when the user goes back to having Internet, it would make those calls. Is there  a good library that would handle this?

Example with Internet:

- User fills out form.
- User has Internet.
- App calls networking, and all is good.

Example without Internet:

- User fills out form.
- User does NOT have Internet.
- App caches the call, and notifies the user it will be posted once they have Internet.
- Sometime later, the user has Internet and the call is made.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Use Volley Library for your requests , if you set setShouldCache(true) then you have the last response you get from specified url , and in OnFail() of your request you can say that get data from Volley's cache .

Comment: Can that cache more than 1 call at a time? Like if I want the user to fill out multiple forms before they get Internet.

Comment: This cache system save last response that get from url , if you send your requests to multiple urls yes Volley can cache all them , but if you send multiple request to one url you can just access the last response in normal way

Comment: I'll have to look into Volley some more and figure out if it fits my needs, thanks. :)